# How to split Internet between TV and Computer

Tags: networking

I have a Samsung big screen smart TV with HDMI ports and an RJ-45 internet port. The TV gets its cable service through one of four HDMI ports. My house is wired for internet (no wireless). The router is in a different room to the TV. I have one dedicated internet drop that must be shared by the TV and a PC that sits next to it.

If I plug an internet drop into the TV I get smart TV access to Netflix and Amazon prime. Other "Smart" features aren't really that smart. That's why I have a dedicated PC next to the TV. It's connected to the TV via a HDMI cable. If I plug my internet connection into the PC, I get much better Google and Internet than through the TV's native "smart" services. Netflix is also much better through the PC than through smart services.

This is great fun for a group.  But, I have to physically move the internet cable back and forth from PC to Smart TV. I would like to not have to move this connection.

Can I use a 5-port gigabit desktop switch and split the one internet connection between the PC and the TV? If not, can you suggest a "wired" solution?

Comment: I am not sure how TVs respond to switches, but it's an easy thing to test. Plug an Ethernet connection from your router to the switch and to Ethernet lines from the switch with one into the PC and one into the TV. Reset your network and see if it works.

Comment: You should be able to. The protocols used to get the network connection to the TV from the drop are the same as if you'd plug a dumb-switch in. Traffic should still flow as expected.

Comment: I'm going to try this once Jason Aller gets back to me in assigned IP vs DHCP.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Provided you aren't using an assigned IP address and instead are using DHCP and your internet provider isn't limiting the number of IP addresses you can be assigned via DHCP it will work.

Some switched have a single port labeled uplink. You'll want to plug the cable running to the wall into this one, and the TV and PC into the other ports.

Comment: Do Comcast, Cox and TimeWarner home accounts use a dedicated IP or DHCP?  I'd like to know before I try mine.  I have one of those three.

Comment: You'd be paying extra to get a dedicated IP address. It is likely that you have DHCP service where they assign you a different address from a pool each time you connect.

Answer (score 0):

I did it with total success using the little SWITCH TP-Link  LS1005G - 10/100/1000Mbps.

It was enough to :

1. conect the switch to the power outlet
2. insert the IN cable in the 1st switch plug and
3. insert the 2 OUT cables in the 2nd and 3rd switch plugs and in the TV and Computer.

Done!